# htaccess RewriteRule resulting in 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a main site in a subdirectory where our main domain is pointed
and a lot of sites in root subfolders. some of they are subdomains.

main site (laravel install):

```
public_html/mainsite/default/public/index.php
```

secondary sites

```
public_html/rec/index.php
public_html/raesta/index.php
public_html/acrup/index.php
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(acrup) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(raesta) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(rec) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mainsite/default/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The main site domain is http://mainsite.edu.ar

The problem is when we try to access http://mainsite.edu.ar/recursos
returns 404

It seems it's matching the /rec part of the url

we already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(rec)/?$  - [L]
```

resulting in:
http://mainsite.edu.ar/recursos works
but http://mainsite.edu.ar/rec doesn't

http://mainsite.edu.ar/raesta and http://acrup.mainsite.edu.ar both works fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/acrup/ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/raesta/ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/rec/ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mainsite/default/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Your first try

```
RewriteRule ^(rec) - [L]
```

was hit by `http://mainsite.edu.ar/recursos` as well as `http://mainsite.edu.ar/rec` because both URIs (everything after the DNS-name `mainsite.edu.ar`) start with `rec`.

Your second take

```
RewriteRule ^(rec)/?$  - [L]
```

didn't work, becuase you made the trailing slash optional with `/?` so still both URIs were hit.

The difference with `RewriteRule ^/rec/ - [L]` is that it explicitly requires `/rec/` --> a leading and trailing slash surrounding `rec`.